# how to compare date with timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, freemarker

I have a date in format yyyy-mm-dd(this date type is "Date"). assume this date as userdate. I have two more dates in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+00(date1 and date2) which is of the type Timestamp. assume these two dates as date1 and date2.
for example: 2022-05-02 18:12:44+00.
**my requirement is if the userdate lies between date1 and date2 I should list some products from the warehouse**. for this, I need to compare the userdate with date1 and date2.
the logic goes like this ..**if userdate is in Between date1 and date2 then loop using  FTL(freemarker template) for listing products**.
the code is mentioned below.

`<input type="date" id="myDate">`

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href='url?date='+ document.getElementById('myDate').value">Submit</a>`

when user clicks on "submit" after selecting date. I'm passing this user selected date from url to other page.now I want to compare this userdate with other two dates which are timestamps.and I'm fetching these two timestamps from database table.

how shall I acheive this when the type of dates are different.

Comment: Which db you are using

Comment: Postgres @dinesh oz

Answer (score 0):

You can simply transfer Date to timestamp by `getTime` method.

```js
let timestamp = date.getTime();
```

or transfer timestamp to Date by `new Date`.

```js
let data = new Date(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the timestamp into a new date object and then compare the values

```js
const date1 = new Date(timestamp1);
const date2 = new Date(timestamp2);

const userDate = new Date(valueReceivedFromInput);

if(date1<=userDate && userDate<=date2){
  // list products from the warehouse
}
```

Note:
If you are only looking to compare `<=` and `>=` then you don't need to use .getTime() unless you are looking to compare dates to check if they are equal like `date1.getTime()===date2.geTime()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var date1 = new Date('December 25, 2017 01:30:00');
var date2 = new Date('June 18, 2016 02:30:00');

if(date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()){
    //same date
}`enter code here`
```

best to use .getTime() to compare dates in js

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)